# How do I integrate Paytm wallet in an Android application?

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I want to integrate Paytm wallet in an Android application as a payment option, just like in the Uber app. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

Paytm has added documentation now. 
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk/

---

They have support for Android, but they don't have any open documentation.

Use this link to contact them and learn more
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/

Comment: Link doesn't exist now!!